# Automatically creating hyperlinks from bibliography to citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I am usually using a combination of BibTeX and `hyperref` to create clickable citations, so a reader can easily jump from my text to the right place in my bibliography. Unfortunately there is no quick way to jump back: you have to manually find the place in the text where you paused your reading. Therefore I would like my reference list to contain hyperlinks to the location(s) in the text where I actually use the references.

Ideally this would work like it does in Wikipedia articles, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkel#cite_note-Hugger.2C_Justin.2C_10_moments_that_define-33), so there is a little clickable `^` if a citation is used once, and `^ a, b, ...` if there are more 'calls' to a certain bibitem.

**Is there a feature (or a package) that provides this functionality?**

I can think of a way to implement this assuming all citations are used only once, but that's not the case in practice.

Comment: `\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}` should work...

Comment: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: I use the shortcut of my pdf viewer to go back (alt+left in adobe and sumatra). I wouldn't have much use of backref numbers as I normally don't remember the page number where I was.

Comment: Hmm, that would also work. I wasn't aware of this shortcut (and apparently, neither were the people who complained about this while reading my docs).